# Reachability working on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, reachability

In my project I am using Reachability class provided by Apple. When there is no internet connection, I am displaying an alert message. Everything is working fine, when I test it on the simulator, but when am running it on iPad, the alert message is not shown when there is no internet.

I am running the code on iOS 5.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
-(BOOL)isInternetConnectionPresent{

Reachability *objReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];    
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [objReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(internetStatus != NotReachable)
{
    return YES;
}


   return NO;
}
```

UPDATE:

Used NSLog to debug. Seems there was some problem with WWAN, even when there was no SIM card. Restarted the iPad & switched OFF & ON the Wi Fi again. Now it works fine. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You're probably gonna get better answers if you add some more details. You could post your implementation code for example. Also try to do some debugging: some `NSLog`s at least. `Reachability` should of course work on devices, too. I use it many apps.

Comment: as i said, it works fine in simulator!!... 
i have edited my question to add the code.

Comment: You might just have to clean the project, delete the app from device... Anyway: you'd really be better off using observer - one of best examples can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3597085/653513)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check all the **NetworkStatus** and Cross Check the device **Wifi Connection status** again

**Example:**

```
// to check if, wifi connected properly in current device.
- (BOOL)networkCheck {

    Reachability *wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"NETWORKCHECK: Not Connected");          
            return NO;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WWAN");
            return NO;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WiFi");
            return YES;
            break;
        } 
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: i have just added my code to check for internet.. it should do the same.

Comment: Apply my answer and check the NSlogs. It should say the exact reason,why there is an connection

Answer (score 0):

In My case the following code snippet is working perfectly with iOS 5. Here i am checking internet connectivity with WIFI.

```
- (NSString *)stringFromStatus:(NetworkStatus ) status {
NSString *string;
switch(status) {
    case NotReachable:
        string = @"Not Reachable";
        break;
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
        string = @"Reachable via WiFi";
        break;
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
        string = @"Reachable via WWAN";
        break;
    default:
        string = @"Unknown";
        break;
}
return string;
```

}

------------------------ now with following line of code you can check.

```
 Reachability *reach =[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] ;
NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
NSLog(@"%@", [self stringFromStatus: status]);

if ([[self stringFromStatus: status] isEqualToString: @"Not Reachable"]) 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Connection Failure !"
                          message:@"Your Device is not Connected to any active WIFI Connection."
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else
{ //connected to internet.
```

}