# Reachability says no coverage when app is installed from Store or TestFlight

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, reachability

I'm having this really weird issue with Reachability on iOS. If I run my app in debug on a device there's no problem at all, the app runs fine. But when I install it from the store or from TestFlight I get my No Coverage error even if I'm on Wi-Fi, but only when I try to do certain actions. If I don't do that specific action the app runs fine until I do.

This is the part of my code that deals with Reachability:

```
- (void)connectionReachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notice {
  NetworkStatus status = [self.connectionReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
  if (status == NotReachable) {
    self.inCoverage = NO;
  } else {
    self.inCoverage = YES;
  }
}

- (void)hostReachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notice {
  NetworkStatus status = [self.hostReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
  if (status == NotReachable) {
    self.inCoverage = NO;
  } else {
    self.inCoverage = YES;
  }
}

- (void)displayAlertOfType:(AlertType)type {
  if (type == AlertTypeNoCoverage) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"No coverage"
                                                    message: @"You current have no data coverage, try again later"
                                                   delegate: self
                                          cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
  }

  if (type == AlertTypeOperationNotCompleted) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Whoops... Something went wrong" 
                                                    message:@"The operation couldn't be completed, try again later" 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
  }

}
```

Comment: What is that "Specific Action".

Comment: Unasociating a social network account, or associating it. It has nothing different than any other net call, but for some reason it goes crazy with it.

Comment: How strong is the WiFi signal.

Comment: Full strength, it's my home network. The thing is if I install the app by compiling it with Xcode it works fine, but form TestFlight or the App Store it fails, even if the archive is the exact same build.

Comment: You should contact Apple.

Comment: Also try to run your app with wifi disabled and only 4G or 3G.

Comment: It's the same result works fine when compiled from Xcode and goes haywire when downloaded.

Comment: Compiled in Debug... Or Release mode? Build to release... And check your local ipa file.

Comment: You are not the only one http://stackoverflow.com/a/14230961/1702413

Comment: How can I build to release? I'm not sure how to change that setting.

Comment: you can set on your target: Optimization Level set to Fastest, Smallest [-Os] in Debug mod (from None) - the same as Release; in that way you can simple "Run" on Device - to more closely simulate the code that will be generated & running on the user’s device.

Comment: maybe is not debug/release issue. The same behavior here: "was from..some problem with WWAN.. there was no SIM card. Restarted the iPad & switched OFF & ON the Wi Fi again. Now it works fine" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247139/reachability-working-on-simulator-but-not-on-device

Answer (score 0):

```
 Reachability *reachability = [Reachability sharedReachability];
 [reachability setHostName:@"http://www.google.com/"]; 
 NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability remoteHostStatus];

if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {
 //no internet connection

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"No coverage"
                                                    message: @"You current have no data coverage, try again later"
                                                   delegate: self
                                          cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
 }
 else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFiNetwork) {
 //wifi connection found
 }
 else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork) {
 //EDGE or 3G connection found
 }
```

Comment: I use this code if I want to check for an Internet Connection. It should work.

Comment: Seems fairly similar to my own. Don't think the problem is actually the code.